# Issue in android 8 - two way streaming using red5 pro

Tags: android, red5pro

Getting an issue in android 8 for two way streaming. Library used for 2 way streaming is Red5. 
Issue: When subscriber stream gets connected then it overlaps the publishing screen so publishing screen just disappears. Used **setZOrderOnTop(true)** & it worked but it also overlaps to the bottom of the screen & the other components like buttons are not visible due to overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Just used below method
r5Videoview.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true) instead of setZOrderOnTop(true).